# Taking residues from complex logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, residue-calculus

Currently completing a practice test and have come unstuck at the following question:

For the function $\frac{1}{e^{2z}-e^z-2}$ state the location and order of each pole and find the corresponding residue.

Thus far I have Identified the 2 simple poles as being $Log(-1)$ and $Log(2)$ - however in the answers I have been provided, my $Log(-1)$ pole has been subsequently changed for $-i\pi$?? I am unsure why or how this has occurred? I'm sure its something simple I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Euler's identity! $-1 = e^{\pi i}$.  $\ln (-1) = \ln (e^{\pi i}) = \pi i.$  But then $e^{3\pi i} = -1,$ too.

Comment: Oh of course! Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}e^{2z}-e^2-2=0&\iff(e^z)^2-e^z-2=0\\&\iff e^z=-1\vee e^z=2\\&\iff z=\pi i+2k\pi i\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}\vee z=\log(2)+2k\pi i\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}.\end{align}It's not a good idea to talk about logarithms in this context, unless it is the logarithm of a real number greater than $0$.

In this case, each pole is a simple pole. For instance, if $z_0=\pi i+2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$, then$$\operatorname{res}_{z=z_0}\left(\frac1{e^{2z}-e^z-2}\right)=\frac1{2e^{z_0}-e^{z_0}}=\frac1{-2-(-1)}=-1.$$